How to resolve startup boot order in creating multiple VMs all at once?
I’ve created a script that successfully created multiple VMs in hyper-v. However, I still have problem with the error displayed regarding startup order. Any suggestions to resolve this issue? Thanks.
Here is my script:
for ($Counter=1; $Counter -le 2; $Counter++) {
    $VMName = "VM0" + $Counter
    $Generation = 1
    $Cpu = 2
    $Memory = 1024MB
    $VMPath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\$VMName"
    $ISOPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\WindowsServer2019.iso"
    $VHDXPath = "$VMPath\DATA_Disk.vhdx"
    $VHDSize = 1GB

    New-VM -Name $VMName -Path $VMPath -MemoryStartupBytes $Memory -Generation $Generation 

    Set-VMProcessor -VMName $VMName -Count $Cpu

    New-VHD -SizeBytes $VHDSize -Path $VHDXPath -Fixed

    Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName $VMName -Path $VHDXPath -ControllerNumber 0 -ControllerLocation 0 

    Add-VMDvdDrive -VMName $VMName -Path $ISOPath -ControllerNumber 0 -ControllerLocation 1

    $Bios = Get-VMBios -VMName $VMName
    $DVD = $Bios.BootOrder | Where-Object { $_.DeviceType -eq ‘DvdDrive’ }
    Set-VMBios -VMName $VMName -StartupOrder $DVD

    Start-VM -Name $VMName
}

Here is the error displayed re: Startup order:
Set-VMBios : Cannot validate argument on parameter ‘StartupOrder’. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and
then try the command again.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\v6\vmsv6.ps1:40 char:46
Set-VMBios -VMName $VMName -StartupOrder $DVD
CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:slight_smile: [Set-VMBios], ParameterBindingValidationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMBios

I've already tried to change the set-VMfirmware to set-VMBios and adjust the controller number and controllerlocation as well as removing the controllertype.

The error message implies that $DVD contains $null, which in turn implies that $Bios.BootOrder | Where-Object { $_.DeviceType -eq ‘DvdDrive’ } produced no output.

"I've already tried to [...]" - can you share what happens when you make the described changes?

You may only have one drive and you need an array.  Try : $DVD = @($Bios.BootOrder | Where-Object { $_.DeviceType -eq ‘DvdDrive’ })

@jdweng: In PowerShell, you never need to worry about passing a single value to an array-typed parameter - PowerShell implicitly creates a single-element array from it when the parameter is bound.
Therefore, what you're suggesting cannot possibly make any difference (leaving aside that the error message clearly suggests a different cause). Try & { param([string[]] $strings) $strings; $strings.GetType().Name } -strings onlyOne

@mklement0 : I had to use the arrays many times to get my code to work.

@jdweng, (a) not in this case, which (b) you can easily verify yourself (I've given you a test command) and (c) you're adding another unhelpful distraction to the one that your first comment amounts to.

@mklement0 : The Microsoft webpage shows using the @ character to make arrays : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.4#the-array-sub-expression-operator  It fixed my code in lots of cases.

@jdweng: @ doesn't make arrays. What you're thinking of (and linking to) is @(...), the array-subexpression operator. It doesn't make (construct) arrays either: it collects the pipeline output from whatever statement(s) it encloses (symbolized as ... here) and outputs it as an [object[]] array. As such, it isn't an array constructor, but an array guarantor. None of this matters here, for the reasons previously explained. You continue to create unhelpful distractions. Arguably, by responding to you, so am I, but I'm still hopeful that my message will eventually be heard.
